# Overriding box redirect url in the oauth redirect

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I can define a url as defined in here: http://developers.box.com/oauth/

and if I don't specify a redirection in the url, that is what is going to be used, but what happens if I specify a redirection url during application creation AND in the URL? Which one should take precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define both, then the one on the url must match the one defined during application creation or you should get an error redirect_uri_mismatch shown to the end user.

This error is explained towards the bottom of the page in the table of errors http://developers.box.com/oauth/

They also explain that redirect_uri_mismatch is one of four errors that are shown directly to the end users from a Box error page, and not returned to your application.

For security against at least one type of attack set it at creation time! 
Then I would just omit it from the url.

I'm linking to oauth.net if you want more info on the attack I am referring to
http://oauth.net/advisories/2014-1-covert-redirect/